# LinearLayout in a RecyclerView doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

Here is what I am trying to do:
[What is the simplest way to create rows that scroll together and are composed of variable sized clickable Views with the same height on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843860/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-rows-that-scroll-together-and-are-composed-of)

Basically create variable width columns that have the same width in every row. Also need to add, delete and add listeners. Seems like a fairly simple task, but I am finding Android's GUI library a lot harder to figure out than Java's and WPF's GUI library.

Here is my RecyclerView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView ampRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter ampAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager ampLayoutManager;

    List<FunctionView> myDataset = new ArrayList<FunctionView>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_ll);
        linearLayout.setWillNotDraw(false);

        ampRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.AmpRecyclerView);

        // use a linear layout manager
        ampLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        ampRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(ampLayoutManager);

        myDataset.add(new FunctionView(this));
        myDataset.add(new FunctionView(this));
        myDataset.add(new FunctionView(this));

        // specify an adapter
        ampAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(myDataset, 1);
        ampRecyclerView.setAdapter(ampAdapter);

    }
}
```

My adapter

```
class MainActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivityAdapter.FunctionViewHolder> {

    private List<FunctionView> views = new ArrayList<FunctionView>();

    private List<LinearLayout> llViews = new ArrayList<>();

    private int rows;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class FunctionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public FunctionViewHolder(LinearLayout v) {
            super(v);
            linearLayout = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MainActivityAdapter(List<FunctionView> myDataset, int rows) {
        views = myDataset;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MainActivityAdapter.FunctionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                     int viewType) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.function_holder, parent, false);
            llViews.add(linearLayout);
        MainActivityAdapter.FunctionViewHolder vh = new MainActivityAdapter.FunctionViewHolder(linearLayout);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivityAdapter.FunctionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        int width = 0;
        for(FunctionView fv : views){
            holder.linearLayout.addView(fv);
            width += fv.getWidth();
        }

        holder.linearLayout.setMinimumWidth(width);
        //TODO set the data
        // holder.functionView = views.get(position);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rows;
    }
```

I know there are glaring design flaws. I am trying to get the scrolling working first, because every layout I try doesn't work how I'd like.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/AmpRecyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the holder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you said there are glaring design flaws, but you need to change the `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` and `android:layout_width` to `match_Parent`.
if your item's hight is `match_parent` then your inner layout's hight becomes the `recyclerview's` hight then there is no room for other items so there will be no scrolling.
also, put something like a `textView` in it to be able to see the items.

another note, the name is supposed to be `item` not `holder`. `holder` is related to `ViewHolder` which is a totally different thing. you can name it according to your activity for example if Your activity name is `MainActivity` so your activity layout is `activity_main`, then you can call the inner layouts `item_main`

I recommend watching a tutorial on youtube or read an article from medium or anywhere (you can simply just google android recyclerview example) to learn the basics.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAMPLE"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added the 3 custom views to the LinearLayout in the RecyclerView and they are there, I can't scroll them though. I also have tried wrap_content and the LinearLayout still only is the width of the parent instead of the content. Also, I am using the developer's guide. My goal is to add and remove items from the LinearLayout after it is added to the RecyclerView, but first I need to get the 3 items I have in there to scroll. Also, I am trying to scroll horizontally.

Comment: if you want to scroll horizontally, o why `ampLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);` ????,

Comment: Because I want to add views (larger than the width of the RecyclerView, and Horizontal LinearLayouts in this case) vertically. The RecyclerView orientation is horizontal.

Comment: I actually want to scroll both ways. I've tried a LinearLayout in a LinearLayout in a HorizontalScrollView in a ScrollView, but that didn't work either.